# Unable to find the location of C++'s standard libraries in OS/X?

Tags: c++, macos

I have looked at /System/Library, but I have not found the iostream library/module by

```
ack iostream
```

**Where are the standard libraries in OS/X?**

Comment: David's answer which he removed solves the problem: the location is /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/gcc/darwin/3.3-fast/c++/iostream

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On OS X 10.10 Yosemite, they're located here:

`/usr/include/c++`

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/index.html) installed first.

Without xcode you won't be able to develop C/C++ applications since xcode includes all linkable standard libraries and headers.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, /usr/local/lib ... Try adding -L/usr/local/lib to your GCC build options. Although the stdc++ libraries *should* be in your linker path already. Compiler errors usually indicate missing headers / syntax error while linker errors indicate missing binary blobbage.

Comment: @Bell: How can you add -L/local/lib to your GCC build options? I did not find a file "~/.gccrc" at my Home.

Comment: Not used OSX much, are you using XCode? You can edit the CC=... line in the Makefile or do it however OSX wants you to :)

Comment: @Bell: Where is the Makefile in Ubuntu/Mac?

Answer (score 1):

for me it is under the Xcode library directory: 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/.

My OS is Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

Apple keeps moving it. To see the current location, run

`xcrun --show-sdk-path`

On Big Sur the location is:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`

Answer (score 0):

Try /usr/lib/ or /usr/local/lib/

Answer (score 0):

On macOS MOJAVE 10.14, it's located at:

```
usr/local/include/c++/
```